# Using *this to initialize a reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constructor, argument-passing

I'm trying to initialize an instance of my class `ShadeRec` with its constructor:

```
ShadeRec(World& world);
```

So I pass to it:

```
ShadeRec sr(*this);
```

where "this" is an instance of the class World.

I get the following error:

```
World.cpp: In member function ‘ShadeRec World::hitObjects(const Ray&) const’:
World.cpp:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘ShadeRec::ShadeRec(const World&)’
ShadeRec.h:17: note: candidates are: ShadeRec::ShadeRec(const ShadeRec&)
ShadeRec.h:15: note:                 ShadeRec::ShadeRec(World&)
```

Assuming the problem is just that the World instance has the attribute `const`, how can I get rid of this error message?

Comment: Does the constructor need a non-const reference? If not, why not make it take a const reference?

Comment: Highly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912445/how-to-discard-const-in-c/2912726#2912726. Also look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598703/c-const-usage-explanation for pointers on how const works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing this in the `hitObjects` member function which is marked as `const`. Think of it this way: that member function is promising not to modify the `*this` object. However, it's happily passing it to a different object by non-`const` reference. What if that other object modified it? Uh oh!

There are two possible solutions that depend on the problem. Does the `ShadeRec` constructor actually modify the passed `World` object?

1. If it does, you should make sure `hitObjects` is not marked as `const`. After all, that would be lying.
2. If not, it should take it by `const World&`. Then it's okay for `hitObjects`, which is marked `const`, to pass `*this` to it.

Comment: It doesnt modify the passed object, ShadeRec uses it to initialise ShadeRec instance's World object. But when I change the parameter to const World& I get an other error.

ShadeRec.cpp: In constructor ‘ShadeRec::ShadeRec(const World&)’:
ShadeRec.cpp:7: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘World&’ from expression of type ‘const World’

Comment: and now I get this: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Point3D::Point3D(Point3D const&)", referenced from:
      ShadeRec::ShadeRec(ShadeRec const&)in cclHIDes.o
      ShadeRec::ShadeRec(ShadeRec const&)in cclHIDes.o
      Ray::Ray(Ray const&)in cclHIDes.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @RupertCobbe-Warburton I'll respond to your first comment first. You have a more fundemental problem. You are passing `*this` which is `const` to the new `ShadeRec` object which keeps a non-`const` reference of the object. That simply can't work. Why doesn't `ShadeRec` keep a `const` reference? Or maybe `hitObjects` shouldn't be a `const` member function.

Comment: @RupertCobbe-Warburton Second comment: That means you've declared a `Point3D` copy constructor but haven't defined it.

Comment: Yes, I had it wrong with the function. Now hitObjects is not const. Hence the second comment.

Comment: What do the other 2 classes have to do with it?

Comment: That was weird, I implemented Point3D 2 weeks ago and I forgot to complete one of the constructors but the error just came today..oh well, thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a `const` reference and a non-constant.

The compiler doesn't want to pass a constant object to a method that takes a non-constant (mutable) object.  That would violate interface agreements:  being able to modify a constant object.

This situation may arise from a constant object calling mutable functions or a constant method calling mutable method.

Comment: An object being passed using a const reference is not a constant object. The word `const` in a const reference is telling nothing about the object, it's just expressing a property of the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Type of `this` pointer within the `const` member function of a `class World` is `const World*`, which means that you can't use it to initialize a non-const reference (you can't just "drop" its *constness*).

Change the type of the argument of `ShadeRec`'s constructor to `const World&`:

```
ShadeRec(const World& world);
```

See C++03, 9.3.2 §1:

> The type of `this` in a member function of a `class X` is `X*`. If the member function is declared `const`, the type of `this` is `const X*`

Comment: It doesnt modify the passed object, ShadeRec uses it to initialise ShadeRec instance's World object. But when I change the parameter to const World& I get an other error. ShadeRec.cpp: In constructor ‘ShadeRec::ShadeRec(const World&)’: ShadeRec.cpp:7: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘World&’ from expression of type ‘const World’

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can construct a `ShadeRec` from a `World` without modifying the passed-in `World`, you need a ShadeRec constructor like this:

```
 ShadeRec(const World& world);
```